# Accelerating code using numba.jit

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I'm trying to accelerate a python program with **`numba.jit`**.

A function of my program multiplies an array of `float`s and a scalar, that is always an integer.

```
import numpy
myarray = numpy.array([0.2,0.26,0.45,0.78],dtype=float)

def multiply(array, scalar):
    newarray = array * scalar
    return newarray

newarray = multiply(myarray,5)
```

When I `numba.jit()` my functions with the following signature, the function runs an order of magnitude slower:

```
fastmultiply = numba.jit("f4[:](f4[:],int8)")(multiply)
```

Is this because I'm declaring wrong datatypes: **`f4[:]`** and **`int8`**?

Or the way my function is coded does not permit a speedup using `numba.jit()`?

Comment: The only thing your function is doing is calling an already optimized numpy function - not much optimization potential there.

Comment: So there is no much to do for increasing performance when working with numpy arrays?

Comment: numba is mainly useful for accelerating code that cannot take advantage of numpy's fast vectorized array options, e.g. cases where you're otherwise forced to use nested Python `for` loops. numpy arrays already have highly optimized methods for multiplication, so it's unlikely that you could do much better using numba in this case.

Comment: Even so, it's quite interesting that compiling the function decreases performance by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Economy of efforts v/s the amount of a generated `jit`-code re-use

**JIT** can help in case, where an amount of re-use justifies a cost of Just-In-Time compilation.

The first run of the code thus takes way longer, as `.jit()` compiler processes the source.

**Beware the economy of efforts** - for "short" code this may take several orders of magnitude longer, than the final jit-compiled product, thus adjusting such an initial cost-of-opportunity penalty may become reasonable only if having millions of re-use cases.

For a much "more computationally intensive" code, typically a non-trivial convolution, iterative re-processing methods et al, the cost of jit-compilation might become justified even for a solo-case.

---

### [`@numba.jit()` signatures](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.19.1/reference/compilation.html)

well, this is a separate subject and wrong types may hang your processing.

**Explicit `.jit()` signatures or `.autojit()`?** That's the Hamlet's dilemma.

Well, it depends on your preferences. **Quantitative evidence** shall be collected about both initial-call  / re-use calls' durations for either of approaches and decide as per the expected amount of re-use calls ( costs / benefits inequality ).

```
#numba.jit( 'f4[:](i4,f4[:])' )                              # .float32 # [DONE] PERF.ToDo.MS:
#numba.jit( 'f4[:](i8,f8[:])' )                   # .float32 # .float64 # [DONE] PERF.ToDo.MS:
@jit(       'f8[:](i8,f8[:])' )                              # .float64 # [DONE] PERF.ToDo.MS:
def numba_EMA_fromPrice( N_period, aPriceVECTOR ):                      # TEST:         perf (non)-jit Stopwatch.start();;Stopwatch.stop()
    ...

# @numba.jit [usec]----------------------------------------- PERFORMANCE PROFILING
aClk.start();numba_EMA_fromPrice( 8, price_H4_CLOSE );aClk.stop()
Out[112]: 160814L                         # 1. JIT-compile
Out[113]:    331L                         # re-use 0.3xy[ms] v/s 11.5[ms] CPython
Out[114]:    311L
Out[115]:    324L
#
# @numba.guvectorize()
# @numba.jit( nogil = True )              # JIT w/o GIL-lock w/ multi-CORE ** WARNING: ThreadSafe / DataCoherency measures **
aClk.start();numba_EMA_fromPrice( 8, price_H4_CLOSE );aClk.stop()
Out[126]: 149929L                         # 1. JIT-compile
Out[127]:    284L                         # re-use 0.28[ms] v/s 11.5[ms] CPython
Out[128]:    256L
```

**Additional costs** of `autojit()` signatures, that require analyzing/adapting,  might deform the edge of a cost / benefit inequality.

**Maintenance** of `.jit()` explicit signatures might turn out to be a headache.

Be carefull:

**first**, `np.float` is **not** **`f4`**

```
|>>> np.arange( 2, dtype = float ).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

**next**, there are cases ( `np.nan_to_num()` is one of such ), that may receive a **"*silently*" up-cast `dtype`** to `np.float64`, which may result in headache making hunt for finding where the heck the `dtype` collides with `numba.jit()` explicit signatures.